# Share config in cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

How I can share config file in cluster with is on failover mode? 
I don't want to edit `artemis-user.properties`, `artemis-role.properties`, and `broker.xml` files on every server in the cluster.

Cluster settings:

- security-enabled: true
- persistence-enabled : true
- paging-directory, bindings-directory, journal-directory, large-messages-directory used from master server

Security settings like this:

```xml
<security-setting match="clusterQueue">
    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
    <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
    <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
    <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
</security-setting>
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't provide any automated way to share configuration between cluster members. However, since all the configuration you referenced is text-based it should be fairly simple to replicate it to your brokers with standard tools and/or infrastructure. For example, you could use SCP to copy the files, create a shared NFS mount with them, etc.

Even in a homogeneous cluster it's common to have small differences in the configuration files (e.g. for the `cluster-connection`, an `acceptor`, etc.). In that case you can use system property substitution (which is referenced in the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html#configuration-files)) to pull out the bits from each broker which need to be customized and then set those in `artemis.profile`, e.g.:

```
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -DmyAcceptor=tcp://192.168.1.10:61616"
```

Then reference that system property in your `broker.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="netty-acceptor">${myAcceptor}</acceptor>
```

In this way you can have the same `broker.xml` shared among all the brokers but each can have their own `artemis.profile` with the unique values that each broker needs.

Comment: I checked few ways and copy file is easy and good only for artemis-user.properties, artemis-role.properties but not for broker.xml. If you have a lot of queues manage them isn't that easy.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the challenges you're facing managing queues?

Comment: I want to have strict security to queues, for example user Test should only send messages to queue testQueue. So when I added this entry to broker.xml on master, I must do the same on slave. I can't share broker.xml file because it is assigned to one server and has specific cluster config like connectors.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. You should be able to share `broker.xml` between all your nodes using system property substitution.

Comment: But how to override e.g connectors, acceptors port or cluster config ?

Comment: As noted already, you should use system property substitution. I've updated my answer to give an example.